# File name out of SSRS with FacilityName_YYYYMMDDHHmmss timestamp

Tags: reporting-services, timestamp, ssrs-2008, filenames

I am looking to create a subscription for a report that runs nightly, the file name requires the format of the date to be YYYYMMDDHHmmss. Adding @timestamp uses _ and does not supply seconds.

Comment: are you using Data Driven subscription? Are you writing to a share or emailing it?